# AWS Sagemaker - add new class to detect

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a successfully trained a sagemaker model that detects a specific object (cans) in images. If I want to add a new class (plastic bottles) to be detected:

1. Can I use my original model and add a new class to be detected?
2. If yes, does my new training set need to have both classes labeled? Eg. I want to start detect plastic bottle ans have a training dataset for it. Do I need to label the cans as well in those images?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic question and prescriptive guidance cannot be provided without understanding what algorithm you are using.

If you are using the SagMaker Object detection algorithm, this algorithm does support [incremental training](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html#object-detection-incremental-training).

Kindly note though that:

```
The input hyperparameters of both the new model and the pretrained model that you upload to the model channel must have the same settings for the base_network and num_classes input parameters.
```

The same is true for SageMaker [image classification algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html#IC-incremental-training)

```
The input hyperparameters of both the new model and the pretrained model that you upload to the model channel must have the same settings for the num_layers, image_shape and num_classes input parameters
```

Comment: I am looking for a SageMaker object detection algorithm (MXNet). I was looking into incremental training and understood that a model can be created based on an existing one. What is unclear to me, is if this new model can detect new object types that weren’t accounted for in the first model. If my first model detects cans, can I use incremental training to identify plastic bottles (with the new model now detecting cans and bottles)?